# Machzor with the Chayei Adam's version of the Seder HaAvodah

Tags: prayer-book, yom-kippur, nuschaot, musaf, chazarat-hashatz

The [Chayei Adam (in Nishmas Adam)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49397&st=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A5+%D7%9B%D7%97&pgnum=569) lists several edits he made in his Machzor for Yom Kippur in the Seder HaAvodah (Amitz Ko'ach) to better correspond with the description of the Avodah brought down in the Gemarah in Maseches Yoma.

Is there a printed Machzor that actually incorporates these edits in the body of the Piyut (as opposed to just mentioning it in the footnotes)?

Comment: Thanks for bringing your question here; welcome to Mi Yodeya! You may also be interested in our 148 other [tag:prayer-book] questions. I recommend you take our [tour] to learn more about how the site works.