# Halachic differences in the Yom Kippur avodah between piyutim

Tags: prayer-book, yom-kippur, musaf, masechet-yoma, yotzrot

There are various piyutim said by different communities to describe the avodah on Yom Kippur.  Are there halachic differences between any of these piyutim?  For example, do they pasken like different tannaim or amoraim in Yoma?

For the purpose of the actual avodah, the halacha will have to be decided by the Sanhedrin.  This question might be relevant if a community is somehow stuck with only the "wrong" machzor and don't have enough copies of the full text of the piyut according to their tradition.  They might want to say another traidtion's piyut, but change relevant lines in it to reflect their psak.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62425/170

Comment: @msh210 yotzrot?

Comment: re your comment to me: well, _musafos_ technically, but usually called _yotz'ros_, yes. But feel free to revert the edit as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/15-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D) (Hebrew) discusses what seems to be a difference of opinion between the various *piyyutim*, namely whether the various lotteries discussed in [Yoma Chapter 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.2?lang=bi) in fact took place on Yom Kippur, or only during the rest of the year.